# Custom edit views in Plone 4

Tags: view, content-type, edit, plone, archetypes

I have created a custom content-type (*Resume*) and I wish to provide a custom 'edit' view. My use-case is very simple, I simply want to show an HTML "disclaimer" box before the edit form.

First of all I have copied:

```
Products/ATContentTypes/skins/ATContentTypes/atct_edit.cpt
Products/ATContentTypes/skins/ATContentTypes/atct_edit.cpt.metadata
```

into **my/product/browser/** as

```
my/product/browser/resumeedit.cpt
my/product/browser/resumeedit.cpt.metadata
```

Then I have defined a new browser:page stanza in **my/product/browser/configure.zcml**:

```
  <browser:page
   for="..interfaces.IResume"
   name="resume_edit"
   class=".resumeview.ResumeEdit"
   template="resumeedit.cpt"
   permission="cmf.ModifyPortalContent"
   />
```

The resume class in **my/product/browser/resumeview.py** is simply:

```
class ResumeEdit(BrowserView):
""" A customization of the Resume Edit form
"""
    __call__  = ViewPageTemplateFile('resumeedit.cpt')
```

Finally, I have changed the default alias for 'edit' in **my/product/profiles/default/types/Resume.xml**:

```
  <alias from="edit" to="resume_edit" />
```

When installed, adding or editing a Resume content type throws this exception:

```
Unauthorized: The container has no security assertions.  Access to 'id' of (Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x1e8b7a50) denied.
```

This is mitigated by providing a patched version of **edit_macros.pt**:

```
85c85
<             tal:attributes="action python:context.absolute_url()+'/'+template.id;
---
>             tal:attributes="action python:context.absolute_url()+'/'+path('template/getId|nothing');
203c203
<                    tal:attributes="value python:(last_referer and '%s/%s' % (context.absolute_url(), template.id) not in last_referer) and last_referer or (context.getParentNode() and context.getParentNode().absolute_url())"
---
>                    tal:attributes="value python:(last_referer and '%s/%s' % (context.absolute_url(), path('template/getId|nothing')) not in last_referer) and last_referer or (context.getParentNode() and context.getParentNode().absolute_url())"
```

Still, this raises the following exception ('id-64121786' is the id of my resume item) :

```
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: file:/home/zope/env26/plone-devel/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.6.5-py2.6.egg/Products/Archetypes/skins/archetypes/widgets/field.pt
   - Line 63, Column 4
   - Expression: <PythonExpr errors.get(fieldName)>
   - Names:
      {'args': (),
       'container': <Resume at /cms/id-64121786>,
       'context': <Resume at /cms/id-64121786>,
       'default': <object object at 0x8e094c0>,
       'here': <Resume at /cms/id-64121786>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x126e7470>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8081/cms/id-64121786/resume_edit>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x117da910>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PloneUser 'admin'>,
       'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.SimpleViewClass from /home/zope/env26/plone-devel/src/my.product/my/product/browser/resumeedit.cpt object at 0x126d8c90>,
       'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x126d8fd0>}
  Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 49, in __call__
   - __traceback_info__: errors.get(fieldName)
  Module PythonExpr, line 1, in <expression>
  Module AccessControl.ImplPython, line 688, in guarded_getattr
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I solve this problem and provide my own customized template for the edit-view of my content-type?

Comment: Note that `atct_edit.cpt` is a FormController template, and just copying it to be used as a regular page template in a Zope3 view is likely to lead to all sorts of problems. The `.metadata` file only has meaning in a skin layer context and is ignored by browser views altogether.

Comment: Some other valuable information on customizing the edit template here: http://www.llakomy.com/articles/new-submit-button-for-archetypes-edit-template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest not copying atct_edit.cpt. All you really need to do is configure an edit template (which it looks like you know how to do) then override the appropriate parts. See documentation [here](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/old/plone_3_theming/buildingblocks/skin/templates/how-to-customise-view-or-edit-on-archetypes-content-items.html) for more information.

Also, I would start with a completely blank edit template first. Then put some valid XHTML in it e.g. <span>Hello world!</span> and make sure you can load the edit template by clicking on the edit button.

Comment: Thanks. But, using the template from the page you linked and filling out some blanks, I still get the same error. It seems to be related to the following TAL definition: *errors options/state/getErrors | nothing;* in the "master" macro.

Comment: Both errors are fairly self-explanatory. "No security assertions" means you are trying to access an object for which you do not have permission (roughly). And "attribute error" means you are asking an object for an attribute it does not have. (In this case, there is no object i.e. Nonetype, so therefore it can have no attributes.)

Comment: You seem not to be understanding the point Martijn made above.  atct_edit is not a Zope3 Browser view.  Put your template in your skins/templates directory, named **resume_edit.pt**.  No zcml required.  It's less than ideal, but I think we have to wait for the death of Archetypes to use real views (if the edit template was a Browser view, it would be easiest to accomplish what you want by just adding a viewlet to the view)

Comment: Thanks Auspex. I solved by copying base_edit.cpt and base_edit.cpt.metadata in *skins/templates* (and renaming them), thus fixing the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: Thanks. This helped me too after hours of scratching my head.

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on alex's answer: an alternative solution could also be providing your own edit form via z3c.form/plone.autoform if you don't object against the extra dependencies. See [this manual](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/schema-driven-forms/form-types/edit-forms) for the basic introduction/idea.

Answer (score 3):

You must use a viewlet to achieve this.

Register a viewlet for every views, make some check on rendering call display what every you want.

So you don't have to recreate the form